# Azure DevTestLab Artifacts - Folder not accessible

Tags: azure, artifacts, azure-devtest-labs

I created an artifact - "TempArtifact". I added a sub-folder inside it called scripts, which contains all scripts which i will call from my main script. But it looks like this folder is not accessible.

When I add a "ls" command in my main script, it just shows my main script and the Artifacts.json (no folders).

should I be doing something extra to access the subfolder inside my artifact or is it a feature which is not supported by DTL-artifacts

Answer (score 0):

Are you using VSO or Github? I know that for VSO, only first level files will be copied. I think it is the same for Github, but not completely sure.

For Windows systems, the artifacts are copied from source control to the remote VM locally at “:\Packages\Plugins\Microsoft.Compute.CustomScriptExtension\1.8\Downloads”, so you can review the scripts being executed. If the execution fails, the scripts will be kept after execution for review - have a look and see what files you have there.

Comment: I am using VSO.

Comment: When I do ls, I get to see all the script files in the first level. So I think "ls" is executing at the correct path.